# "Specified network name is no longer available" in Httplistener

Tags: web-services, network-programming, httplistener

I have built a simple web service that simply uses HttpListener to receive and send requests.  Occasionally, the service fails with "Specified network name is no longer available".  It appears to be thrown when I write to the output buffer of the HttpListenerResponse.

Here is the error:

> ListenerCallback() Error: The specified network name is no longer available   at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

and here is the guilty portion of the code.  responseString is the data being sent back to the client:

```cs
buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
output = response.OutputStream;
output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

It doesn't seem to always be a huge buffer, two examples are 3,816 bytes and, 142,619 bytes, these errors were thrown about 30 seconds apart.  I would not think that my single client application would be overloading HTTPlistener; the client does occasionally sent/receive data in bursts, with several exchanges happening one after another.

Mostly Google searches shows that this is a common IT problem where, when there are network problems, this error is shown -- most of the help is directed toward sysadmins diagnosing a problem with an app moreso than developers tracking down a bug.  My app has been tested on different machines, networks, etc. and I don't think it's simply a network configuration problem.

What may be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Do you have any code you can post?  Something stripped down showing the error would be very helpful.

Comment: added some more details, austin.

Comment: No, no resolution yet, @CraftyFella.

Answer (score 7):

I'm getting this too, when a `ContentLength64` is specified and `KeepAlive` is `false`. It seems as though the client is inspecting the `Content-Length` header (which, by all possible accounts, is set correctly, since I get an exception with any other value) and then saying "Whelp I'm done KTHXBYE" and closing the connection a little bit before the underlying `HttpListenerResponse` stream was expecting it to. For now, I'm just catching the exception and moving on.

Comment: New thoughts about that after ten years? Do you know what is the inner reason of `System.Net.HttpListenerException: Specified network name is no longer available`?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich I was never able to attribute it to a problem a user actually experienced. The application that was swallowing it as a Windows service running HttpListener swallowed it for 7 years without incident before I rehosted it in a traditional ASP.NET web app so I could move it to Azure

Comment: I'm getting this too. seems to only happen when returning http 500

Answer (score 0):

I've only gotten this particular exception once so far when using HttpListener.
It occurred when I resumed execution after my application had been standing on a breakpoint for a while.

Perhaps there is some sort of internal timeout involved? Your application sends data in bursts, which means it's probably completely inactive a lot of the time. Did the exception occur immediately after a period of inactivity?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but other threads suggest ignoring the Exception.

[C# problem with HttpListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801868/c-sharp-problem-with-httplistener)

May be that's not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

For me I find that whenever the client close the webpage before it load fully it gives me that exception. What I do is just add a try catch block and print something when the exception happen. In another word I just ignore the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you're trying to respond to an invalid request. Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenerexception?view=net-5.0). I found out that the only way to solve this problem is:

```
listener = new HttpListener();
listener.IgnoreWriteExceptions = true;
```

Just set **IgnoreWriteExceptions** to true after instantiating your listener and the errors are gone.

---

**Update:**
For a deeper explanation, `Http` protocol is based on `TCP` protocol which works with streams to which each peer writes data. `TCP` protocol is peer to peer and each peer can close the connection. When the client sends a request to your `HttpListener` there will be a TCP handshake, then the server will process the data and responds back to the client by writing into the connection's stream. If you try to write into a stream which is already closed by the remote peer the Exception with "Specified network name is no longer available" will occur.