# C# problem with HttpListener

Tags: c#

I wrote a Windows service using an `HttpListener` to process the requests from points asynchronously.

It works fine, but sometimes it runs into a problem that requires restarting the service or server to fix. Initially I declared the listener object with:

```
public HttpListener PointsListener = new HttpListener();
```

Here is the code of the method, where I starting listening. I'm calling it from the `OnStart` method of the service:

```
    public string ListenerStart()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!PointsListener.IsListening)
            {
                PointsListener.Prefixes.Add(String.Concat("http://*:", points_port, "/"));
                PointsListener.Start();
                PointsListener.BeginGetContext(PointProcessRequest, PointsListener);

                LogWriter("Http listener activated on port " + points_port);
                return "Listener started";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Listener is already started!";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            LogWriter("Error in LIstenerStart \r\n" + err.ToString());
            return ("Error: " + err.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here are the methods which process requests:

```
    private void PointProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        response.KeepAlive = false;
        System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;

        try
        {
            //declaring a variable for responce
            string responseString = "<html>My Response: request is not allowed by server protocol</html>";


            // Commands and actions to set responceString

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            LogWriter("Error in PointProcessRequest: \r\n" + err.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                output.Flush();
                output.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                LogWriter("Error in PointProcessRequest CLOSING OUTPUT STREAM: \r\n" + err.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                PointsListener.BeginGetContext(PointProcessRequest, PointsListener);
            }
        }
    }
```

It is working well some of the time, but the following error appears in the log:

```
Error in PointProcessRequest: 
System.Net.HttpListenerException: The specified network name is no longer available
   в System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   в ARK_Dealer.ark.PointProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)

[26.01.2011 9:00:54] Error in PointProcessRequest CLOSING OUTPUT STREAM: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.
   в System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   в System.IO.Stream.Close()
   в ARK_Dealer.ark.PointProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
```

I think that problem appears when some point sends the request to server but before the receiving answer looses the connection.

How can I prevent the exception from being thrown? Will be the response object be properly disposed of automatically? How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using a HttpListener in production and I've found the nicest way to resolve this issue, without adding a whole bunch of try/catch blocks which do nothing to communicate the logic of the code at hand; is to quite simply to set `Listener.IgnoreWriteExceptions = true;` and, voilà no more write exceptions!

Comment: That is wrong on so many levels! What if you are writing to the stream constantly, and the other side closes the connection for some reason, you wouldn't get the exception thrown on Write() call because you are ignoring write exceptions, and your app will continue to write to the stream, which to it looks like it is open...

Comment: IgnoreWriteExceptions is way to go. I disagree with Cipi and his "edge case" which doesn't even make sense for HTTP protocol.

Comment: @Lubos, Cipi's response makes perfect sense.  What if your request is for downloading a large file.  If you ignore the exceptions, you will continue to read from the file even though the bytes will never reach the client.

Comment: The best way really is to catch the error, and then stop sending more data.  You may choose to ignore it if you wish in your capture of the event, but it's bad form to keep sending data to a session that is otherwise closed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429439/specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available-in-httplistener) about this.

What you are doing is fine, since there is nothing else that can be done about the other side closing the connection or the connection being dropped.  You might want to catch the exact exception and call `output.Dispose()` and other cleanup or simply let the finalizers handle the release if it doesn't happen very often.

Comment: I little bit correted PointProcess method and inserted Dispose there as you wrote. Let me monitor the system several days to see will it take effect or no. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello again! Please comment my final decision, when writing the reponse to output stream I use following code:                   
using (System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream)
{
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

If exception will occur, it will be written to log, and if code runs, object output will be disposed automatically. Am I correct? Thank you!

Comment: Are you still closing the `response` object somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently, and solved it by wrapping the output in a try/catch:

```
try
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
catch (HttpListenerException)
{
    // Handle error caused by connection being lost
}
```

Comment: As you see in my code it's already in try catch, that's why I can log exception and listener is not stopping... But I'm trying to find a solution preventing writing to output stream if current connection is no more available. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved!!! I just removed this:

```
finally
{
PointsListener.BeginGetContext(PointProcessRequest, PointsListener);
}
```

and inserted this command at the begin of PointProcessRequest method!

```
IAsyncResult _result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(PointProcessRequest), listener);
```

Problem solved at 100%!!!